# Generics Interface spezialisation

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I try to give my generic interface a base.

**Declaration**:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    ObservableCollection<object> Items {get;}
}

public interface IMyInterface<TValue>
{
     new ObservableCollection<TValue> Items {get;} //Try to override base Items
}
```

**Implementation**

```
public abstract class MyBase<T> : IMyInterface<T>
{
    private ObservableCollection<T> = _Items;
    public ObservableCollection<T> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _Items;
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<T> IMyInterface.Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _Items as ObservableCollection<T>; //Reason?
        }
    }
```

**Usage**:

```
void foo(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(IMyInterface obj in e.NewItems) // e.NewItems are derived from MyBase
    {
        var item = obj.Items; // Problem: item = null
        //Do something
    }
}
```

But if i try to use it in that way, i got null.

What is my mistake? Exists any other, better ways?

Comment: Where did you implement that interface?

Comment: not evident from your posted code ... post some more relevant code

Comment: Updated Implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation is the problem here. The cast will result in `null`. You can only use covariant interfaces, so the first `Items` should be an `IEnumerable<object>`:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    IEnumerable<object> Items { get; }
}

public interface IMyInterface<TValue> : IMyInterface
{
    new ObservableCollection<TValue> Items { get; } //Try to override base Items
}

public abstract class MyBase<T> : IMyInterface<T> where T : class
{
    private ObservableCollection<T> _Items;
    public ObservableCollection<T> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _Items;
        }
    }

    IEnumerable<object> IMyInterface.Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _Items;
        }
    }
}
```